# What actually happens in inheritance (java)?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;

    A(int i,int z) {
        a = i;
    }

    void abc() {     
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
    }
}
```

```
class B extends A {
    int a = 55;
    int b = 66;

    B() {
        super(14,13);
        super.b = 99;
    }
}
```

```
public class test {    
    public static void main(String[] argue) {
          B obj = new B();
          obj.abc();
    }
}
```

output:

```
a is 14
b is 99
```

I would refer to the above code for my questions. I don't have some basic OOP concepts vivid. Please clear my doubts regarding the following queries:

1. What actually happened when class B extended A? Was the code from A copied pasted in B, each variable defined in A is now defined in B also and each method definition in A is now also in B?
2. As a class is just a template it lists the attributes that the object will have and the memory will only be allocated for each variable definition in a class when its object is made. Now if you say that when class B extended A the code from class A was not copied pasted into B i.e. the variables (int a, int b) originally defined in A their definitions are not pasted in class B.When the object of class B is created it allocates memory for variables 'a' and 'b' in class B, not of class A as their definition is not copied pasted in B. How can class B use the super class variables 'a' and 'b' even though the super class wasn't instantiated i.e. 'a' and 'b' don't exist in memory as class just defines a template. Does the compiler allocate separate memory portion for 'a' and 'b' on special consideration for class B as it extended class A? What about the method defined in the class A?
3. I was expecting obj.abc() (*the last statement in the main method*) to print:

   ```
   a is 55
   b is 66
   ```

   as the method abc() was originally defined in class A and now class B inherits A so it inherited abc(). So if I called abc() with a reference of class B's object it should have printed the values of 'a' and 'b' in class B i.e.

   ```
    a is 55
    b is 66
   ```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why this question has 3 down votes?

Comment: because this is not the kind of [questions expected at this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)? "Picture Programmers like a small conference room with a whiteboard. _No computer_, no books, no papers. You write your question on the whiteboard and experts walk by. Someone sees one that they can answer, they stop in and help..."

Comment: I'm just going to warn you that any answers that are complete are likely to dive fairly deep into the Java Language Specification.  How the *language* behaves is described in [The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) and how the *machine* behaves is in [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html). Understanding these is in part necessary for the answer to "what actually happened when the class B extended A".

Comment: I have re-edited the output sorry for the wrong one .

Comment: I know i shouldn't have posted this question here rather it should have been on stackoverflow, and i did post it there but for no reason they started down-voting, so i came here.

Comment: In its current form, the main issue with this question is that it's too many questions in one question. Each of these is probably answerable on its own (though they likely already have answers on SO and many other sites already; I suspect "low research effort" is the reason others have downvoted this), but talking about how the Java language behaves *and* how the various JVMs are allowed to implement that behavior is definitely too much for one Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you describe does not correspond to the code you posted. It actually prints

```
a is 14
b is 99
```

I'll get to why that's happening later. But first, I'll rewrite your code into a form that demonstrates the relationships typically found in inheritance:

```
public class A {
    int a;
    int b;

    A(int i, int z) {
        a = i;
        b = z;
    }

    void abc() {
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    B() {
        super(14, 13);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    B obj = new B();
    obj.abc();
}
```

Which gives the output

```
a is 14
b is 13
```

This is inheritance in its simplest form, and has the following characteristics:

- An instance of `B` contains two member variables, `a` and `b`. These variables are defined by class `A`.
- When you *invoke* the method `abc()` on an instance of `B`, the JRE determines that the method is actually defined in class `A`. This is known as dynamic dispatch, and is one of the key features of inheritance.

Now a modification:

```
public class B extends A {
    B() {
        super(14, 13);
    }

    @Override
    void abc() {
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
    }
}
```

Here I've *overridden* the method `abc()` in class `B`. When the JVM examines the class, it determines that `B` has defined the method, so invokes that implementation and does not look for an implementation in `A`.

Because `B` extends `A`, and the member variables `a` and `b` are not declared `private` by `A`, `B` has access to those variables. The output is:

```
b is 13
a is 14
```

Another modification:

```
public class B extends A {
    B() {
        super(14, 13);
        super.b = 99;
    }

    @Override
    void abc() {
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
    }
}
```

This highlights the construction chain. In an inheritance hierarchy, a class' constructor must call a superclass' constructor. So here, `B()` explicitly calls `A(int,int)`, which implicitly calls `Object()`.

The ordering is important: immediately after the call `super(14,13)`, the value of member variable `b` is 13. However, the `B()` constructor changes that value, so the program prints

```
b is 99
a is 14
```

I left the assignment as `super.b = 99`, but in this case it could also have been just been `b = 99`, because class `B` has access to the variable defined by `A`. However, this form becomes important in the next revision.

Let's bring this program one step closer to your original:

```
public class B extends A {

    int a = 55;
    int b = 72;

    B() {
        super(14, 13);
        super.b = 99;
    }

    @Override
    void abc() {
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
    }
}
```

In this case I'm *redefining* the variables `a` and `b` within class `B`. These definitions *shadow* the definitions from class `A`. This is where it gets tricky -- and why, in production code, shadowing is a code smell.

- There are now *four* variables in the class instance. Two are defined by class `A`, and two are defined by class `B`.
- The code in class `B` will ignore the variables defined by `A`
- *Unless* you explicitly prefix the variable reference with `super`

So, after construction, here are the four variables:

- `a`, defined by `A`, with the value 14
- `b`, defined by `A`, with the value 99
- `a`, defined by `B`, with the value 55
- `b`, defined by `B`, with the value 72

Note that the variable `b` defined by `A` was explicitly changed by `B`'s constructor, *after* it was assigned by `A`'s constructor, because `B`'s constructor referred to it with `super`.

However, the definition of method `abc()` in `B` doesn't prefix those variables with `super`, so it will print the values of the variables defined by `B`:

```
b is 72
a is 55
```

Last step: I remove the definition of function `abc()` from class `B`.

```
public class B extends A {

    int a = 55;
    int b = 72;

    B() {
        super(14, 13);
        super.b = 99;
    }
}
```

Now the JRE again invokes the function defined in `A`. However, this implementation only has access to the two variables that are also defined by `A`; it has no knowledge of the two variables defined by `B` even though they exist within the object instance. So the output is

```
a is 14
b is 99
```

Why isn't `b` `13`? Because the constructor for `B` explicitly referenced the variable defined by `A`.

Anyone who feels the need to add references to specs should feel free to do so; I don't think they're necessary.

Comment: I would say i am highly impressed by your logical presentation of ideas and very sound reasoning.I cannot thankyou much for this answer.You have answered each and every part of my question in a both precise and concise manner.I am sorry i don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer but i am marking it as "The accepted answer".Again thanyou, may people like you live longer for the good fate of the programming community !.